# IE does not display Response in new pop-up window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In my application, I pop-up a new window then set the Response display on it. 
It worked in all of browser versions in my development and testing environments (IE10, IE9, IE11). 
But in my customer's browsers using the same IE version as mine, it does not work. 
They said they updated some security patches from Microsoft. I tried to run on Chrome, and it worked. I tried some ways to simulate that issue in my PC, but the browser still can show the response. 
Is there any configurations to solve it on browser? Below is my code.

```
var etc = "channelmode=0,dependent=0,directories=0,fullscreen=0,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,toolbar=0" + ",scrollbars=no,left = 0 , top = 0 , height=" + screen.availHeight + " , width=" + screen.availWidth ;
var newWindow = window.open('', "MyWindow123", etc );
newWindow.focus();
document.forms[0].target="MyWindow123";
d.action="POST";
d.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues

- in your paste, "d" is not set
- d.action is set to "POST" but you meant d.method or d.action="someurl"
- you could very likely have a security issue. It could also be a timing issue. Well known in IE
- show what is calling the statements you posted. If it is a link, you need to cancel the click

Try this where I also removed all illegal spaces in the parms and removed unnecessary ones:

```
function myPost() {
  var etc = "resizable,scrollbars,status,left=0,top=0,height="+screen.availHeight+",width="+ screen.availWidth;
  var newWindow = window.open('', "MyWindow123", etc );
  if (newWindow) {
    newWindow.focus();
    var d = document.forms[0];
    d.target="MyWindow123";
    d.method="POST"; // NOT action!!!
    setTimeout(function() {document.forms[0].submit();},300);
  }
  else {
    alert("Sorry your browser does not allow popups");
  }
  return false; // cancel the event
}
```

assuming (inline here, unobtrusive is better)

```
<a href="pleaseenablejavascript.html"
  onclick="return myPost()">Submit</a>
```

or

```
<form action="someurl" onsubmit="return myPost()">...
```